# "Variable is not available in the current GLSL version"

Tags: opengl, glsl, lwjgl

I am attempting to create a tessellation shader:

```
#version 410 core                                                                               

// define the number of CPs in the output patch                                                 
layout (vertices = 3) out;                                                                      

uniform vec3 gEyeWorldPos;                                                                      

// attributes of the input CPs                                                                  
in vec3 WorldPos_CS_in[];                                                                       
in vec2 TexCoord_CS_in[];                                                                       
in vec3 Normal_CS_in[];                                                                         

// attributes of the output CPs                                                                 
out vec3 WorldPos_ES_in[];                                                                      
out vec2 TexCoord_ES_in[];                                                                      
out vec3 Normal_ES_in[];                                                                        

float GetTessLevel(float Distance0, float Distance1)                                            
{                                                                                               
float AvgDistance = (Distance0 + Distance1) / 2.0;                                          

if (AvgDistance <= 2.0) {                                                                   
    return 10.0;                                                                            
}                                                                                           
else if (AvgDistance <= 5.0) {                                                              
    return 7.0;                                                                             
}                                                                                           
else {                                                                                      
    return 3.0;                                                                             
}                                                                                           
}                                                                                               

void main()                                                                                     
{                                                                                               
// Set the control points of the output patch                                               
TexCoord_ES_in[gl_InvocationID] = TexCoord_CS_in[gl_InvocationID];                          
Normal_ES_in[gl_InvocationID]   = Normal_CS_in[gl_InvocationID];                            
WorldPos_ES_in[gl_InvocationID] = WorldPos_CS_in[gl_InvocationID];                          

// Calculate the distance from the camera to the three control points                       
float EyeToVertexDistance0 = distance(gEyeWorldPos, WorldPos_ES_in[0]);                     
float EyeToVertexDistance1 = distance(gEyeWorldPos, WorldPos_ES_in[1]);                     
float EyeToVertexDistance2 = distance(gEyeWorldPos, WorldPos_ES_in[2]);                     

// Calculate the tessellation levels                                                        
gl_TessLevelOuter[0] = GetTessLevel(EyeToVertexDistance1, EyeToVertexDistance2);            
gl_TessLevelOuter[1] = GetTessLevel(EyeToVertexDistance2, EyeToVertexDistance0);            
gl_TessLevelOuter[2] = GetTessLevel(EyeToVertexDistance0, EyeToVertexDistance1);            
gl_TessLevelInner[0] = gl_TessLevelOuter[2];                                                
}
```

However, when I run my game, I get the following error:

```
Error: 1281
Tessellation shader wasn't able to be compiled correctly. Error log:
ERROR: 0:? : '' :  Incorrect GLSL version: 410
WARNING: -1:65535: 'GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location' :  extension is not available in current GLSL          version
WARNING: 0:4: 'vertices' : symbol not available in current GLSL version 
WARNING: 0:? : 'gl_InvocationID' : variable is not available in current GLSL version 
WARNING: 0:? : 'gl_InvocationID' : variable is not available in current GLSL version 
WARNING: 0:? : 'gl_InvocationID' : variable is not available in current GLSL version 
WARNING: 0:? : 'gl_InvocationID' : variable is not available in current GLSL version 
WARNING: 0:? : 'gl_InvocationID' : variable is not available in current GLSL version 
WARNING: 0:? : 'gl_InvocationID' : variable is not available in current GLSL version 
WARNING: 0:? : 'gl_TessLevelOuter' : variable is not available in current GLSL version 
WARNING: 0:? : 'gl_TessLevelOuter' : variable is not available in current GLSL version 
WARNING: 0:? : 'gl_TessLevelOuter' : variable is not available in current GLSL version 
WARNING: 0:? : '
```

My game appears to be ignoring the shaders, but I guess that is expected with so many errors?
[image]

I have already tried [googling the error](http://i.gyazo.com/eead8a0b59d4a8e77adcddaafe78bfba.png), however I am unable to find any solution or even information on why this is happening.

How can I fix the above errors so my shader can run correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you probably don't have a OpenGL-4.1 core context to begin with, and thus your shaders won't compile. Instead of debugging the shaders, I suggest you look at your context creation code and double check your system is cabable of giving you a 4.1 version context.

Comment: How do I get an "OpenGL-4.1 core context"? How do I see if my version can give me a 4.1 version context?

Comment: OpenGL version: 4.0.0 - Build 9.17.10.2857 - So that means I can only use stuff of OpenGL 4 and below? Does this mean I can't use my tess shader?